# Grainy rings on photos after stacking StarryLandscapestacker

Tags: post-processing, image-stacking

I am having an issue that I am hoping for help here.  I take astro pictures using:
Nikon D850 with a Sigma 14mm F1.8 Dg ART lens on a tripod.  I usually take a 6-10 images of the the night sky and denoise with a stack in starry landscape stacker (SLS).  Every once is a while after stacking in SLS I end up with a photo with grainy ridges and rings. Any idea what could be causing this?  The exposure here is ISO 6400 for 13 seconds at F1.8.

[image: Rings in photo bottom left is the most clear]

Comment: Some possibilities: [What causes faint circles in astrophotography images?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/41433/75526) / [What is the “Newton Effect”?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/7628/75526) / [What causes and how can I avoid this moiré pattern in a composite night sky photograph?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/45655/75526)

Comment: Does the software perform lens correction before stacking? Is there any improvement if you turn it off?

Comment: On a hunch... I wondered if the source files were RAW.  I checked the software site and found that RAW files aren't supported.  This makes me wonder if white-balance issues occurred during conversion and not all frames had a common white balance.  You might explore your source data.

Comment: Thanks, Xiota - the software does not perform lens correction.  Will take a look at the links you provide.

Comment: Thanks, Tim - I have to convert to tiff first.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you're setting White Balance manually? I think this may be related to differences in Auto White Balance color temperature between the shots.

Comment: This makes total sense, thank you.  I experimented with temps around 4200 and I does not happen.  It could very well be the auto white balance.  Will check out again this week.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This could be, as already pointed out, effects triggered by the initial processing of the images.

The web site has instructions for how they should be pre-processed before loaded into SLS:

https://sites.google.com/site/starrylandscapestacker/preparing-images-for-starry-landscape-stacker

In summary, they are:

- reduce the contrast
- turn off sharpening and noise reduction
- apply lens chromatic aberration corrections - but turn off all other lens corrections
- Set custom white balance

Comment: Thanks Pete - this was the fix